# Generics in HashMap implementation

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

In the Java implementation, I found

```
 transient Entry[] table; 
 which is initiated in constructor as
 table = new Entry[capacity];
```

I know and understand that creating generic array is not allowed but then what I fail to understand is that how the whole thing works. I mean when we do something like

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

How does above codes leads to creating an Entry array of type `<Integer, String>`

Well, few people are not able to understand what I am asking. To rephrase what I am asking is what is the point in doing something like

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

When it does not result in

```
Entry<Integer, String>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You seem to have worked out exactly what happens, it uses an array of `Entry` raw types. As a side note, this isn't `native` code, it's simply JDK code.

Comment: Thanks, I will correct 'native' part. What I am trying to ask is .. How does this <Integer, String> parameter is passed on to Entry class to ensure Entry<Integer,String>

Comment: @Walt regarding your last edit: because `new Entry<K, V>[capacity]` (or `new Entry<Integer, String>[capacity]`) is invalid Java code. It doesn't compile. You may not create arrays of generic types.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation makes an array of `Entry<K,V>` objects of type

```
static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V>
```

without providing generic type parameters ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.Entry)). This is allowed, but it comes with understanding that the compiler is no longer guarantees type safety. For example, in other places in code you could write

```
Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
```

and the compiler will let you do that. If you know for sure that you always set elements of `table[]` to `null` or `Entry<K,V>`, then you know that the assignment is correct.

The reason this works without a problem is that generic types in Java are implemented through type erasure, i.e. there is no difference at runtime between `Entry<K,V>` objects `Entry<Integer,Integer>` and `Entry<String,Long>`.

Comment: This answer is correct. The downvoter should also downvote mine if he/she doesn't agree, but he/she should explain why.

Answer (score 7):

Generics are a compile-time safety. At runtime, the map only know about Objects. This is known as *type erasure*.  To scare you even more, the following code will run without problem:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> safeMap = new HashMap<>();
Map unsafeMap = safeMap;
unsafeMap.put("hello", "world");
```

You'll get a warning at compile time, because you're using a raw Map instead of a generic one, but at runtime, no check is done at all, because the map is a good old map able of storing any object. Only the compiler prevents you from adding Strings in a map or integers.

Answer (score 2):

Try to think of Java Generics this way: type parameters only apply to the *static type of reference-typed expressions* and do not apply to the *type of actual instances* being referred to by the reference values at runtime.

I find the above key to developing the proper intuitions when reading Java code. So the next time you see

```
new HashMap<Integer, String>()
```

read it as follows: "This is an instance creation expression of the type `HashMap<Integer, String>`. At runtime this expression will yield a reference to an instance of the `HashMap` class." As long as the compiler can precisely track what you do with the result of that expression, it can maintain the knowledge that this is indeed a `HashMap<Integer, String>`, but no further than that.

Now, since the static type system is not powerful enough to track the type parameters on the component type of arrays (the fact that Java's array types are covariant plays strongly here), the code is forced to break out of the static type safety network. The key observation is that on its own, this does not make the code *incorrect*, it only constrains the power of the compiler to find programming mistakes. This is why Java allows you to make unchecked casts from raw into generic types, although not without a warning which marks the spot where you have left the provinces of static type safety.